# SparkJob generate file on remote server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I need some advice for the following problem:

I have a Spark cluster with Cassandra.
I need to write a spark job (using Scala) to extract some informations out of Cassandra. I need to generate a file with the result and put it on another server (where there is no Spark).

My question is: What is the best solution for that ?
1. Generate the file on the same server as spark and then do a scp to copy it on my destination server ?
2. Is there another way to generate the file right on my destination server ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do so would be to compute the results and store them in some directory in HDFS (server with spark) and nfs mount this directory to some path in your destination server (server without spark).

Let me know if this helped. Cheers.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I need to copy the file to 2 remote servers (I have some other distributed stuff). Is it possible to nfs mount a HDFS to 2 remote servers ?

Comment: Not bad your idea, but I was thinking starting from your idea and maybe I will use a rsync instead. I think it would be better for what I need

Comment: rsync is designed to send 1000s of small files across the network. NFS is NOT. NFS is designed to act as if it's a local file system that has to communicate with a remote host for most operations. using rsync you're basically creating a copy of all those files on the destination server. I believed that is something you dont want to do thats why i didnt suggest it.

Comment: Actually on my destination server I have kettle jobs that will upload these files. So basically I need the file on each one of my destination server.